# When are auto layout constraints resolved?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, viewwillappear, adaptive-design

I have a little problem, it seems that in the `viewWillAppear`auto layout constraints are not yet resolved. Indeed, I'm working with the new adaptive UI, and the default size is 600x600, not representing any of the real device sizes. But when I launch the simulator, size of the main view during the `viewWillAppear` is still 600x600, and not the real device size!!!

So when can I really test the final size of my views **before** it's displayed? Because you can understand I do not want to do it in the `viewDidAppear` and have some kind of flicker for the user...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

When the bounds change for a view controller’s view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method.

Comment: I knew it! Thanks a lot!